# Points outside a closed set are separated from that closed set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $G \subseteq X$ be a closed set, and $x \in X \setminus G$ be a point outside $G$. Then there exists an $\varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$ such that $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap G =\emptyset$.

**Hint**: To prove this aim for a contradiction,

1. Suppose this wasn't true, and understand what that means.
2. Argue that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, under this assumption there must be at least one point in $B_{\frac{1}{n+1}}(x) \cap G$.
3. By appealing to the Axiom of Choice, define a sequence $a_n$ by requiring that each $a_n \in B_{\frac{1}{n+1}}(x) \cap G$.
4. Prove that this sequence converges.

Assume for contradiction that $\forall \varepsilon>0$ we have $B_{\varepsilon}(x) \cap G \ne\emptyset$ whenever $(X,d)$ is a metric space with closed set $G \subseteq X$ and $x \in X \setminus G$.

Suppose $(a_n) \in G \ni (a_n)$ convergent and let $(a_n) \to l$, where $l \in G$. Because $G \subseteq X$, then $(a_n) \in X$ and $l \in X$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $n>N$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $d(a_n,l)<\varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$. So for $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{n+1}$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $d(a_n,l)<\frac{1}{n+1}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Initially I was thinking about defining a sequence $a: \mathbb{N} \to X$ by $a(n)=x$. But I don't think that'll work since that would mean $x=l$, but $x \in X \setminus G$.

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Probably the simplest reasoning is this: since G is closed X\G is open, so for every point x in G there exists an epsilon such that the epsilon ball around x is contained in X\G, and thus has empty intersection with G.

Comment: @Ramanujan why for every point $x \in G$? Shouldn’t it be for every point $x \in X \setminus G$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

This follows trivially from the definition of an open set in metric space since the closed sets are defined to be complements of open sets and open sets are defined to be possibly uncountable unions of open balls, each point not in a closed set must be contained in an open ball, then using triangle inequality you can show that there exists a ball centred in x that satisfies the wanted condition exists.

Comment: why is it that each point not in a closed set must be contained in an open ball? Is it because the complement of a closed set is open? So $\forall x \in X \setminus G, \exists \varespsilon >0 \ni B_{\varepsilon}(x)\subseteq X \setminus G$. Do you mean that the point must be contained in an open set? By definition, the open ball with radius epsilon is a subset of $X \setminus G$ provided $X \setminus G$ is an open set?

Comment: Each point not contained in a closed set must be contained in an open ball because the closed sets are defined as complements of open sets, and open sets are defined as arbitrary unions of open balls in metric topology therefore if a point is an element of an open set, then it must be contained in an open ball.

Comment: how would you define the sequence so that each $a_n$ is in the intersection given in hint #3?

Comment: my method doesn't require defining such a sequence. it has the advantage of being simpler and not requiring axiom of choice.